# Pages need to be reloaded for JavaScript to work when using menu links in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, localhost

When I load the page on localhost:3000 all JavaScript files work fine but when click menu links (localhost:300/some-page) the pages load fine but remote scripts like Google Places don't work unless I reload the page. Here are my files:

[webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/1051c43aaa39f215ceb383e1f4be9e95)

[App.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/364d99019afb3b09292ca381a9697b92)

[Header.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/6f796f81e380c36dbb61662808642b60)

[index.html](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/b2811e2191e9420663e5de03b4ccb42f)

[index.js](https://gist.github.com/dantenovski/5efdab2da6ff9f1631a9303b5a843e37)

Comment: Place  `google API fetch call` under `componentWillMount`. It will work without reloading of pages. Moreover, I cant able to find `fetch call` in any of your specified links.

Comment: Why do I have to fetch Google Places API? It's just a CDN script file in index.html.

Comment: CDN is fine. Where your accessing those CDN based tags?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's expected behavior.The Google Places API script hooks to an existing DOM when the script is loaded. When I navigate around the page, some DOM is added, some is removed. The DOM that was added will not be "enchanced" by Places API but we reload the page then it no longer starts on index -> pageA, it starts on pageA and that pages DOM is already generated before Google Places loads